# Fitting a confidence interval to dlmForecast in R

Tags: r, confidence-interval, dlm

I've fit a Dyanmic Linear Model to some data using the dlmFilter in R [from the dlm package]. From said filter I have predicted 7 steps ahead using the dlmForecast function. The predicted outcome is very good, but I would like to add a 95% confidence interval and [after a lot of testing] have struggled to do so.

I've mocked up some similar code, below:

```
library(dlm)

data <- c(20.68502, 17.28549, 12.18363, 13.53479, 15.38779, 16.14770, 20.17536, 43.39321, 42.91027, 49.41402, 59.22262, 55.42043)

    mod.build <- function(par) {
  dlmModPoly(1, dV = exp(par[1]), dW = exp(par[2]))
}

# Returns most likely estimate of relevant values for parameters
mle <- dlmMLE(a2, rep(0,2), mod.build); #nileMLE$conv
if(mle$convergence==0) print("converged") else print("did not converge")

mod1 <- dlmModPoly(dV = v, dW = c(0, w))
mod1Filt <- dlmFilter(a1, mod1)
fut1 <- dlmForecast(mod1Filt, n = 7)
```

The forecast outcome appears to be very good [although the model to some extent over-fits the data due to the small number of observations]. However, I would like to add a 95% confidence interval and have struggled to figure out how to do so.

Any advice would be appreciated?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
hwidth <- (outer(sapply(fut1$Q, FUN=function(x) sqrt(diag(x))), qnorm(0.025, lower = FALSE)) +as.vector(t(fut1$f)))
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: My data is not normally distributed and the confidence intervals continue to be far too high as a result. Does anyone have any ideas?